# How to concatenate a string to the end of a command statement in Python

Tags: python, dynamic, command, polymorphism, concatenation

I have a list of classes called `nodes` which consists of instances of the class Node.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, bucketNumber ,colorONE, colorTWO,
                 colorTHREE, colorFOUR, colorFIVE):
        self.bucket = bucketNumber # index
        self.color1 = colorONE # quantity
        self.color2 = colorTWO # quantity
        self.color3 = colorTHREE # quantity
        self.color4 = colorFOUR # quantity
        self.color5 = colorFIVE # quantity
```

I ask the user what color number they want.  I want to be able to take that int and concatenate the word "color" and the number.  Then I want to be able to access that variable such as

```
valueE = (raw_input("Enter color number"))
valueE = int(valueE)
print nodes[0].color+valueE
```

How can I do this or something like this?

Answer (score 3):

Put your colors in a list or dict instead of separate variables:

```
self.colors = [colorONE, colorTWO, colorTHREE, colorFOUR, colorFIVE]
print node[0].colors[valueE - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of colors or a dictionary. (I am using a dictionary in the example below)

```
>>> color = {1: "X", 2: "Y"}
>>> color[1]
'X'
>>> color[2]
'Y'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
valueE = (raw_input("Enter color number"))
print(getattr(nodes[0], "color"+valueE))
```

This is untested.  Look up the documentation for `getattr()`.

Comment: The work, I just had to type cast valueE into a string and add it to color

Comment: Ok, I removed the int cast, so that `valueE` remains a string.  If you like my answer, remember to select it as the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, bucketNumber, colorONE, colorTWO, colorTHREE, colorFOUR, colorFIVE):
        self.bucket = bucketNumber
        self.colors = [colorONE, colorTWO, colorTHREE, colorFOUR, colorFIVE]

valueE = int(raw_input("Enter color number"))
print nodes[0].colors[valueE-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print eval('nodes[0].color%d' % valueE)
```